# ISO 3166-1 and ISO 3166-2 data plus borders (e.g. as kml)

Tags: data-request, geospatial, metadata, geocoding

I am looking for a free or even commercial data source for ISO 3166-1 and [ISO 3166-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) data, ideally with border data (e.g. in kml). The ISO 3166-1 and ISO 3166-2 data should contain the hierarchical relationships as shown in the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I've started to collect a list of world (country, cities, etc.) datasets, guides, etc. in the [Awesome World List @ Planet Open Data](https://github.com/planetopendata/awesome-world). For example, the GeoNames, Natural Earth, etc. datasets might be some candidates. Cheers.

Natural Earth Data
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/
you can download shapefiles here, not kml

Comment: Hi Gerald, thanks for that. I appreciate your feedback. I guess I am looking more for a 'sanctioned' official data source. I understand that this a stack exchange side for open data but I need to use the data in a commercial environment. Thanks.

Comment: the natural earth data @Gerald Bauer mentioned uses this.

Answer (score 4):

I just created a GitHub repo with a world shapefile of ISO 3166-1 entities, based on Natural Earth 1:10m Cultural Vectors.

https://github.com/sdesabbata/world_shapefile_ISO3166-1

The repo includes ready to use shapefiles, original data and script. Please note that there are a few ISO 3166-1 entities that still need fixing (see issue 1).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a script that will attempt to add ISO3166-2 data to Natural Earth 2.0 admin_1_states_province polygons: https://gist.github.com/migurski/4a5821699e1ed519a604

The output can be found in this repository at
https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/blob/master/10m_cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.dbf (and related unmodified shapefile in the same folder)

Comment: Geonames also marks things in its APIs with ISO3166-2:
http://api.geonames.org/get?geonameId=1271874&username=demo